# connecting a client socket from a python cgi script under the apache server

Tags: python, apache, sockets

I can setup a python sockets client and server under fedora19, no problem.
When I place the client portion in a cgi script and execute under apache server
an exception occurs when sock.connect(server_address) is executed.
m I trying something not possible ie a python cgi script that attempts to tart interprocess communication to a listening sockets server?
Help appreciated!
Code from the cgi script as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# 
    import sys
    import cgi
    import socket
    import cgitb
    cgitb.enable()
# added code from mySocketsClient.py
    def htmlTop():
     print("""Content-type:text/html\n\n
     <DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8" />
           <title> MyServer Template </title>
           </head>
           <body>""")
    def htmlTail():
     print("""<body/>
           </html> """   )
    def getData():
     formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
     firstname = formData.getvalue("firstname")
     return firstname

    def creSockettoServer():
# Create a TCP/IP socket
     sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
# 
     server_address = ('localhost', 1080)
     sock.connect(server_address)
# Send data
     message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'
     sock.sendall(message)
     return

#main program
    if __name__ == "__main__":

        try:

            htmlTop()
            print("Hello World from my Server cgi Python Script ")
            firstName = getData()
            print( "Hello {0}".format(firstName) )
            htmlTail()
            creSockettoServer()

        except:
            cgi.pri_exception()
```

Comment: Please post the entire error message, including any stack backtrace.

Comment: I know the failure is at sock.connect(server_address) but do further debug yet, sorry.

Comment: Hi 1) after correcting cgi.pri_exception to cgi.print_exception a trace back is reported

Comment: The trace back is "error: [Error 13] Permission denied". 3) executing the cgi  script directly ( not from under apache) it works and the socket connects. Do I need to change a permission?

Comment: It is possible that your script file is lacking execute permission. **On the apache server,** confirm that it has execute permission. `ls -l foo.cgi` displays the permission, `chmod a+x foo.cgi` turns on execute permission.

Comment: sock.connect( server_address) is executed. Any explanation would be appreciated. I note I am using TCIP socket protocol and Unix Sockets appears to be another choice for inter process communications. Any explanation/guidance greatly appreciated!

Comment: Addtion to previous comment ls -l returns -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1373 May 2 15:21 mysockettoserver.cgi

Comment: Hi Sorry for the typo you corrected.  I'm very new to the forum.Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I've now  tried changing owner and group to apache apache and to myloginname but to no avail.

Comment: Also converted to the Unix Sockets method. Failure remains at the client socket connection. The cgi script works fine when executed from /var/www/cgi-bin but fails socket connection when called from apache.

Comment: I am too facing same problem. If run any socket binding Python script on server command line it’s runs perfectly :
Let’s say — python test.py contains below and connection is successful.
s.connect((‘x.x.x.x’,2778))

But if I try to execute it using http CGI it fails with error
lynx or curl http://hostname:8080/cgi-bin/test.py
“Could not connect, check ip port”